# Crossplatform background service + GUI

Tags: c++, qt, boost, background

This seems to be typical application:
1. One part of the program should scan for audio files in background and write tags to the database.
2. The other part makes search queries and shows results.
The application should be crossplatform.

So, the main search loop, including adding data to database is not a problem. The questions are:
1. What is the best way to implement this background working service? Boost(asio) or Qt(services framework?)? 
2. What is the best approach, to make a native service wrapper using mentioned libraries or emulate it using non gui application?
3. Should I connect gui to the service(how they will communicate using boost or qt?) or directly to the database (could locks be there?)? 
4. Will decsision in point 1 consume all CPU usage? And how to avoid that? How to implement scanning for files less cpu consumable?S

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) which has a convenient ServerApplication class, which can be used in an application that can be run as either a normal command-line application, or as a Windows service, or as a *nix daemon without having to touch the code.

If you use a "real" database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server), then querying the database from the GUI application is probably fine and easier to do. If you use another type of database that isn't necessarily multi-user friendly, then you should communicate with the service using loopback sockets or pipes.

As far as CPU usage, you could just use a bunch of "sleep" calls within your code that searches files to make sure it doesn't hog the CPU and IO ports. Or use some kind of interval notification to allow it to search in chunks periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ServerApplication seems to be what i need, but if services framework from Qt provides has the same functionality, it is a bit more preferable (there is a GUI also, one lib in two applications is better). Are you familiar with this technologies? Are they the same?

Comment: 2. It is rather casual app, so i'm planning to use sqlite. Using poco, is it possible to connect service from Qt gui app? Seems, SFW uses Qt's "reflection" to access the service. Using sqlite directly is blocking, as far as i understood. So will you suggest to use smth like mysql? 3. So, main loop in ServerApplication should be done in main() method, using sleeps there would be ok, right? Or sould i spawn additional thread? Or, are there some kind of main loop in poco like qt has?

Comment: I have never really used the Qt services framework, so I can't comment on that. I tend to use Poco for services because I find Qt to be a pretty heavy weight library, so I only use it in applications where I need a heavy GUI. You can definitely interface between Poco and Qt, but interfacing between Qt GUI and Qt services may very well be easier to do.

Comment: And yes, if you're going to use SQlite, then you will probably want to let your service handle all accesses to it, and have your GUI communicate with the service. MySQL may be a bit heavy for what you're doing, but if not then it would be preferable.

Comment: So quick reply! Thanks! I'm looking into ServerApplication and Task - that seems what i need. The only questions left are: how to communicate between service and qt gui (what is _loopback_ sockets)? Any typed interface possible? There is an ORB in poco, would you suggest it? Mysql will not block either of components, right? But gui need only reading from db and service writing, so will sqlite still block components?